# JQUERY : Move Div back and forth within other DIV

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, slide

Trying to make a DIV move back and forth within the confines of a container DIV. Right now it continues sliding off to the right instead of resetting and going back left.

Ideally it should be re-sizable biased on the containing DIV box. Code below:

```js
 var RIGHT = 1;
 var LEFT = 0;
 var bookDirection = RIGHT;
 var containerwidth = $("#container").width();
 var objectwidth = $("#book").width();
 var displacement = 150;
 var maxwidth = containerwidth - objectwidth / 2;
 var minwidth = 0 + objectwidth / 2;

 setInterval(function(){

  var currentposition = $("#book").position().left;
  $("#output").text("currentposition: " + currentposition + " > Displacement: " + displacement + " >Max width: " + maxwidth);
  $("#output").text("summed: " + (currentposition + displacement));
  $("#output2").text("max is: " + maxwidth);
  //console.log("Book direction is: " +bookDirection);
  if(currentposition + displacement <= maxwidth && bookDirection == RIGHT)
  {
   console.log('hit if');
   $("#book").animate({
    left: "+=" + displacement, 
   }, 1000, function(){
   // Animation complete. 
   });//inner function call - anim complete
   bookDirection == RIGHT
  }
  else if(currentposition + displacement >= minwidth && bookDirection == LEFT )
  { console.log('hit else if');
   console.log('direction : ' + bookDirection + 'displacement: ' + displacement);
   bookDirection = LEFT;
   $("#book").animate({
    left: "-=" + displacement, 
   }, 1000, function(){
   // Animation complete. 
   });//inner function call - anim complete
  }
  else if(currentposition + displacement > maxwidth && bookDirection == RIGHT){
   console.log('here');
   $("#book").stop();
   bookDirection = LEFT; 
   console.log(bookDirection);
  }// end IF
 }, 0); // setinterval
```

```css
body{
 color: red;
}
#container{
 width: 1000px;
 height: 200px;
 border: solid 2px black;
}
#book{
 position: relative;
 left: 10px;
 background-color: black;
 width :100px;
 height :100px; 
}
```

```html
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="day044.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="day044.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="clickme">
   Click here
  </div>
  <div id="container"></container>
  <img id="book">
  <div id="output"></div>
  <div id="output2"></div>
  <div id="output3"></div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a work-around that works well. Leaving question up because seems like
 a common enough desire to do. Note this might prove unwieldy if trying to scale
 for multiple objects so if someone has a better solution, by all means :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var counter = 0;
var inner = 0;
var direction = 1;

function backLeft(){
    $("#book").animate({left:"-=500",},5000,function(){

    });
}
function backRight(){

        $("#book").animate({left:"+=500",},5000,function(){
            backLeft();
        });
}
function update(){
    var currentposition = $("#book").position().left;
    console.log("counter " + counter);
    backRight();
}
setInterval(function(){

    update();
},10000);
});// document.ready
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the setInterval because you use the animate function. Such a function already has a time value.

My proposal is:

```js
var RIGHT = 1;
var LEFT = 0;

function moveObj(containerwidth, containerLeft, objectwidth, displacement, bookDirection, howManyTimes) {
  if (howManyTimes <= 0) {
    return; // ends
  }
  var currentposition = $("#book").position().left;
  var lDisplacement = displacement;
  switch (bookDirection) {
    case RIGHT:
      if ((currentposition + objectwidth) < (containerwidth + containerLeft)) {
        if (Math.abs(containerwidth + containerLeft - currentposition - objectwidth) <= displacement) {
          lDisplacement = Math.abs(containerwidth + containerLeft - currentposition - objectwidth);
          bookDirection = LEFT;
          howManyTimes--;  // on change direction decrease..
        }
        $("#book").animate({
          left: "+=" + lDisplacement
        }, 1000, function () {
          moveObj(containerwidth, containerLeft, objectwidth, displacement, bookDirection, howManyTimes);
        });
      } else {
        bookDirection = LEFT;
        moveObj(containerwidth, containerLeft, objectwidth, displacement, bookDirection, howManyTimes);
      }
      break;
    case LEFT:
      if (currentposition   > containerLeft) {
        if (currentposition < displacement) {
          lDisplacement = currentposition - containerLeft;
          bookDirection = RIGHT;
          howManyTimes--;  // on change direction decrease..
        }
        $("#book").animate({
          left: "-=" + lDisplacement
        }, 1000, function () {
          moveObj(containerwidth, containerLeft, objectwidth, displacement, bookDirection, howManyTimes);
        });
      } else {
        bookDirection = RIGHT;
        howManyTimes--;
        moveObj(containerwidth, containerLeft, objectwidth, displacement, bookDirection, howManyTimes);
      }
      break;
  }
}

$(function () {
  $('#clickme').on('click', function (e) {
    moveObj($("#container").width(), $("#container").offset().left, $("#book").width(), 150, RIGHT, $('#hmTimes').val());
  })
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 2px black;
}

#book {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

How many times: <input id="hmTimes" type="number" value="2">
<button id="clickme">Click here</button>
<div id="container">
    <img id="book">

    <div id="output"></div>
    <div id="output2"></div>
    <div id="output3"></div>
</div>
```